# Написать запросы, осуществляющие следующие операции:

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане и программисты. Требуется ваша помощь. Есть таблица:

```
CREATE DATABASE `auction2` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
  USE auction2;
  --
  -- Таблица `auction`
  --

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `auction`;
  SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
  CREATE TABLE `auction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `specifics` text NOT NULL,
  `place_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `fk_auction_place_idx` (`place_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_auction_place` FOREIGN KEY (`place_id`) REFERENCES `place` (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 --
 -- Добавление данных в таблицу `auction`
 --

  LOCK TABLES `auction` WRITE;
  INSERT INTO `auction` VALUES (1,'2019-05-23 18:40:00','Выставляются на продажу картины великих 
  мировых художников',1),(2,'2019-05-10 12:00:00','Московский аукцион',2),(3,'2019-06-25 
  13:00:00','Июньский аукцион',2);
  UNLOCK TABLES;

  --
  -- Таблица `item`
  --

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `item`;
  SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
  CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


  -- Добавление данных в таблицу`item`

  LOCK TABLES `item` WRITE;
  INSERT INTO `item` VALUES (1,'«Мона Лиза».  Леонардо да Винчи 1503–1506'),(2,'«Рождение Венеры».  
  Сандро Боттичелли 1482 — 1486'),(3,'«Сотворение Адама». Микеланджело 1511'),(4,'«Утро в сосновом 
  лесу». Иван Шишкин, Константин Савицкий 1889'),(5,'«Девочка на шаре». Пабло Пикассо 1905'), 
  (6,'Системный блок'),(7,'Мышь'),(8,'Клавиатура'),(9,'Гантель 10кг');
  UNLOCK TABLES;

  --
  -- Таблица `lot`
  --

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `lot`;
  SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
  CREATE TABLE `lot` (
  `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `final_price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`auction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lot_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `composite` (`auction_id`,`lot_id`),
KEY `fk_lot_auction1_idx` (`auction_id`),
  KEY `fk_lot_item1_idx` (`item_id`),
  KEY `fk_lot_man1_idx` (`seller_id`),
  KEY `fk_lot_man2_idx` (`customer_id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lot_auction1` FOREIGN KEY (`auction_id`) REFERENCES `auction` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lot_item1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lot_man1` FOREIGN KEY (`seller_id`) REFERENCES `man` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lot_man2` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `man` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Добавление данных в таблицу `lot`
--
LOCK TABLES `lot` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `lot` VALUES (1,30000.00,0.00,0,1,1,1),(1,40000.00,0.00,0,2,1,2), 
(1,70000.00,0.00,0,3,1,3),(2,10000.00,0.00,0,4,1,4),(2,20000.00,0.00,0,5,1,5), 
(2,500.00,70000.00,1,6,2,1),(2,1.00,50.00,1,7,2,2),(2,3.00,0.00,0,8,2,3),(2,20.00,0.00,0,9,2,4);
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Таблица `man`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `man`;
 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE `man` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `patronymic` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_man_role1_idx` (`role_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_man_role1` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Добавление данных в таблицу `man`
--   
LOCK TABLES `man` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `man` VALUES (0,'Неопределенный человек','Неопределенный человек','Неопределенный 
человек',1),(1,'Василий','Продажник','Петрович',1),(2,'Куст','Покупакин','Игорьевич',2);
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Таблица `place`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `place`;
 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE `place` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


  --
  -- Добавление данных в таблицу `place`
  --

  LOCK TABLES `place` WRITE;
  INSERT INTO `place` VALUES (1,'Санкт-Петербург'),(2,'Москва');
  UNLOCK TABLES;

  --
  -- Таблица `role`
  --

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `role`;
  SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
  CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  --
  -- Добавление данных в таблицу `role`
  --

  LOCK TABLES `role` WRITE;
  INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (1,'Продавец'),(2,'Покупатель');
  UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Прошу вашей помощи реализовать к ней следующие запросы:

1. Для указанного интервала дат вывести список аукционов в хронологическом порядке с указанием наименования, даты и места проведения. Для каждого из них показать список выставленных вещей.
2. Для указанного интервала дат вывести список продавцов, которые принимали участие в аукционах, с указанием для каждого из них списка выставленных предметов.
3. Вывести список покупателей и для каждого из них — список аукционов, где были сделаны приобретения в указанный интервал дат.
4. Добавить для продажи на указанный пользователем аукцион предмет искусства с указанием начальной цены.

Мои некорректные запросы:

Первый запрос:

```
SELECT a.specifics, a.datetime, p.name FROM auction a INNER JOIN place p ON 
p.id=a.place_id WHERE a.datetime >= '2019-03-25' AND a.datetime <= '2019-05- 
15'
```

Второй запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id FROM man m INNER JOIN lot l ON l.seller_id = m.id INNER 
JOIN auction a ON a.id = l.auction_id WHERE DATE(a.datetime) = '2019-05-10' 
AND m.id > 0
```

Третий запрос:

```
 SELECT m.id FROM man m INNER JOIN lot l ON l.customer_id = m.id INNER JOIN 
 auction a ON a.id = l.auction_id WHERE DATE(a.datetime) = '2019-05-10' AND 
 m.id > 0
```

Четвертый запрос:

```
 INSERT INTO item (description) VALUES('Гантель 10кг'); INSERT INTO lot 
 (seller_id, start_price, item_id, auction_id, lot_id) VALUES(2, '2000', 
 9,2,4);
```

Comment: Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic 

Если вы знаете, что ваши запросы некорректны, значит знаете в чём ошибка в результатах. Попробуйте погуглить, как это исправить.

Comment: Во-первых: это не домашнее задание, данную задачу я нашёл в интернете и пытаюсь решить самостоятельно, пробую изучить MySql.

Comment: Во-вторых: если я смог бы решить самостоятельно, то не обратился бы сюда. Сюда я обратился после многих и не вполне удачных попыток сделать всё согласно задания.

Comment: Ну и последнее: я не прошу решить за меня!!! В данном случае большая часть сделана! Я прошу всего лишь помочь подкорректировать и подсказать где смог допустить ошибку. Спасибо за отзывчивость и за помощь!!!

Comment: 1. Там написано "в хронологическом порядке". Значит в запросе должен быть order by

Comment: 2. Там написано вывести список продавцов с предметами. Не вижу вывода предметов в вашем запросе.

Comment: 3. то же что во втором, просят пользователей с аукционами, у вас на выводе только id

Comment: 4. Почему вы вставляете значение 9 в качестве item_id во вторую таблицу. И даже не смотрите с каким id вставили сам предмет. Используйте функцию last_insert_id()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нулевой запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE `auction2`.`lot` 
CHANGE COLUMN `customer_id` `customer_id` INT NULL ;
```

Первый запрос:

```
SELECT 
    a.specifics, a.datetime, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(i.description) description
FROM auction a 
INNER JOIN place p ON p.id=a.place_id 
LEFT JOIN  lot l ON l.auction_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN item i ON i.id = l.item_id 
WHERE a.datetime BETWEEN '2019-03-25' AND '2019-06-15'
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.datetime ASC;
```

Второй запрос:

```
SELECT m.*, GROUP_CONCAT(i.description) description
FROM auction a 
LEFT JOIN  lot l ON l.auction_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN man m on m.id = l.seller_id
LEFT JOIN item i ON i.id = l.item_id 
WHERE a.datetime BETWEEN '2019-03-25' AND '2019-06-15'
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY a.datetime ASC;
```

Третий запрос:

```
SELECT m.*, GROUP_CONCAT(i.description) description
FROM auction a 
LEFT JOIN  lot l ON l.auction_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN man m on m.id = l.customer_id
LEFT JOIN item i ON i.id = l.item_id 
WHERE a.datetime BETWEEN '2019-03-25' AND '2019-06-15'
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY a.datetime ASC;
```

Четвертый запрос:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO item (description) VALUES('Гантель 10кг'); 
INSERT INTO lot (seller_id, start_price, item_id, auction_id, lot_id) VALUES(2, '2000',  LAST_INSERT_ID(), 2, 5);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное